# Calling an entity category in Objective-C iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a category:

```
#import "Users+Authentication.h"

@implementation Users (Authentication)

- (void) users:(NSSet *)userEmails inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
   // Saves the users to sqllite
```

I know how to call it if it were a class method ( + (Users ....) but how do I call this from my view controller correctly?

Comment: Have you added the method to the interface file? It should be just transparent: send the message to an instance of type Users.

Comment: oohhhh so create an instance of type users like Users *u = [[Users alloc] init]; and then do [u users:...... correct?

Comment: Exactly, [Apple has a good read on categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the method is declared in Users+Authentication.h. Then make sure you import that file wherever you need to use it.